# Sklearn One Class SVM

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to use OneClassSVM in [Sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/) for outlier detection.
A user is visiting websites everyday but one day he visits a website which has never been visited before. I want to catch this outlier using OneClassSVM. Below is a sample data:

```
`([[www.makeuseof.com,
www.kickstater.com,
www.google.com,
www.mashable.com`
```

Below is sample test data

```
`test_data = ['www.makeuseof.com','www.google.com','www.abc.com',]`
```

I am hashing all the string using python built in hashing library.
`abs(hash('string'))`

I am expecting it to return `-1` for `www.abc.com but its`-1` for all.

Comment: Show us some code that fails. I'm not sure that hashing is the best way to go here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are probably some implementation bugs as well, but in general I think hashing will cause your data to be way too spread out, so basic hashing will not let you accurately predict outliers in this case since everything will be so far away from everything else that, well, everything will kinda be an outlier.

For your task, I don't know why you even need machine learning. Use a dictionary that stores the visited websites and when you get a new site check whether or not it's in the dictionary. Fast, efficient and easy.

Comment: I think you are right and that is what I did initially but after some research I found One class SVM is a pretty standard way of finding outliers. So I wanted to try and see how it works. What would be a good way to convert string to numeric so that it could be used in training a SVM ?

Comment: @Vishal - you want something that will keep similar entries close together. For text data, TF-IDF transformations are usually used. But you need real words for that, I don't think it will work well with website URLs. For that, you'd need to define the similarity between two websites, which I don't really know how to do. I would keep it simple: if you can do it without machine learning, you should.

Comment: Yeah you are right TF-IDF is not going to work in this case and for finding similar websites I will need data of the whole web, then categorize it.. It was a hard way but even I found that I should not do it using machine learning..

Comment: Agree with you. Machine Learning is not needed for this problem. Brilliant rule: Don't Complicate Things

Answer (score 0):

Here a short explanation why you should not use machine learning methods:

This is not a machine learning task. In essence machine learning is used to learn unknown patterns from noisy data. It is non-deterministic process.
An examples for such a pattern is

> "If a client is unemployed, under 25 years old and does not have high school diploma, his risk for credit loan default increases by 30% compared to all male clients."

In your case the pattern is known and can be described as

> "User visits a page that he never visited before".

It is a deterministic pattern, hence you should not use machine learning methods here.